# Bathroom Toilet + Shower Venting Fitting Question

Tags: bathroom, shower, toilet, venting

Is this acceptable layout and appropriate fittings to use for the bathroom toilet on the left and shower on the right? Or would you replace any fitting and rearrange layout?

[image: Bathroom Toilet and Shower Venting Fitting diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice picture - looks correct to me. The vent is for sure close enough.

Comment: yeah, the roof vent will go much higher, its just a cropped representation